# Calculating and storing precomputed average with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Say I have a set of products and each product has a set of reviews. Each review has a score. I will need the average of the scores much more often then I will need the actual reviews. Are there any best practices/clean ways of precomputing the average and storing it with hibernate.

I am currently thinking of adding review count and review sum columns to the product table and rigging the add review method to update the count and sum.

I would be very glad to hear of a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against keeping a sum column on your parent table.  If two competing requests attempt to update the sum column, one will fail or you risk clobbering the sum with a stale read (unless the system doesn't have high traffic...).

The queries you require are quite simple and any decent db should give good performance for awhile (lazy psuedo SQL/HQL):

1) A particular avg review score for a product:

```
select sum(score)/count from reviews where product_id = ?
```

2) List of products and their avg review scores

```
select product_name, sum(r.score)/count(r.score)
from products p
join reviews r
group by product_name
```

For the first query, make sure you have some sort of index on product_id on the reviews table.

Using hibernate, you can use projection queries either through HQL or the [Criteria objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection).  If that's not fast enough, then I would look into [second level caching and query caching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html).

Turn on `show_sql` and TestTestTest to make sure hibernate is only hitting the database once, and that your cache is invalidated when new items are added/updated.

Comment: I'm going to go with this or a trigger bundled with a call the get the product with CacheMode.REFRESH after adding or updating a review.

Comment: There is actually an better way to evict from the 2nd level cache. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-sessioncache

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way, a background process to run every now and then and do this update for count and total of rating in product table based on review table.

Another idea is to use a trigger whenever there is a update in review/rating table it will take it into account (using time stamp) and update the product table.

Comment: My idea are based that let your application do what it is meant to. This is something similar to aggregate or analytics, let it be handled separately, for eg. some other day you may need "rating growth in last month", so we can prefer to keep this sort of functionality away from our regular update code.

Comment: If a trigger was used wouldn't the stale data remain in the 2nd level cache?

Comment: @user472749 I don't understand what you are asking, If we use trigger It will update the count in product table to count+1 and rating to rating +thisRating so that next time a data is fetched from product table and avg is calculated it will be correct.

Comment: I was thinking the next retrieval might not go to the db as hibernate would not know about the trigger and invalidate the copy in the cache. Thus a get request would get the stale cached object.

Comment: yes you are right that will happen, I dont have a better solution. If somebody knows how to do it please post it here, I am also interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate query caching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) might be the way to go. Otherwise, go with your original idea.